# Close mobile navigation when tapping anchor link

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I've built a navigation using Elementor/Wordpress and I'm using an anchor link in it. I can't make the navigation overlay close when tapping the anchor link.

This is the HTML, when the mobile menu is opened:

```
<div id="burgerbar" class="site-navigation-toggle-holder show elementor-active">
   <div class="site-navigation-toggle" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="true">
      <i class="eicon-menu-bar" aria-hidden="true">
         <span class="menu-bar"></span>
         <span class="menu-bar"></span>
         <span class="menu-bar"></span>
      </i>
      <span class="screen-reader-text">Menu</span>
   </div>
</div>
<nav class="site-navigation-dropdown show" aria-hidden="false">
   <div class="menu-primary-container">
      <ul id="menu-primary" class="menu">
         <li>
            <a>###</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a>###</a>
         </li>
         <li class="anchor">
            <a href="#site-footer">Anchor</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

This is the HTML, when the mobile menu is closed:

```
<div id="burgerbar" class="site-navigation-toggle-holder show">
   <div class="site-navigation-toggle" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false">
   <!--Same content inside-->
   </div>
</div>
<nav class="site-navigation-dropdown show" aria-hidden="true">
    <!--Same content inside-->
</nav>
```

I've gone through numerous of tutorials and scripts, but none of them have worked for me. I'm not 100% comfortable with JS, so it's really hard for me to customize those scripts to my specific case.

I'm really thankful if anyone could help me solve this one! :)